# How to declare a value selected in HTML as a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have the following code:

```
<span id="text">Change</span>
<P>
<select class="selector">
    <option value=X1a selected>X1a</option>
    <option value=X2a>X2a</option>
    <option value=X3a>X3a</option>
    <option value=X4a>X4a</option>
</select>
<P>
<span id="WW"></span>
<script>
    let X1a = '"Hello"'
    let X2a = '"Watcha"'
    let X3a = '"Hiya"'
    let X4a = '"YouHoo"'
    let ZZ = text
    document.getElementById("WW").innerHTML = ZZ;
</script>
```

As you can see, I am selecting a value with id=text. I now want the value in "text" to be a variable in the `document.getElementById` line to print out the appropriate greeting. But it outputs `[object HTMLSpanElement]`. How do I make the value which I select a variable for the purposes of the `document.getElementById` line?

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/). Please next time tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re looking for the properties `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`. Here’s the differences: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-textcontent-and-innerhtml/. They both allow you to get the value inside a HTML tag. Here’s an example with your code:

```js
let ZZ = document.getElementById("text")
document.getElementById("WW").innerHTML = ZZ.textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `ZZ.textContent` - [MDN Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

However, I'd personally store a reference to the element using `getElementById` just to make it clear what I'm doing, like so:

```
let textElement = document.getElementById('text');
document.getElementById("WW").innerHTML = textElement.textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem very well. You can do :

```
let ZZ = document.getElementById("text").textContent
```